# react load local storage at first

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react app like where I have `App.js` which includes my `Headers` and `Footers` ..

In there I am storing my `state` to local storage.. After storing I can retrieve it ..

But I am having problem on loading it.. In my browser when I do `localstorage['key']` it gives me the data but I am unable to load.

Where should I load it first ?

I have `Root.js` :

```
class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store } = this.props
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <ReduxRouter />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default Root
```

and `index.js` at outer level :

```
const store = configureStore()


render(

    <Root store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Where should I load my `localStorage` ?

Need help . I need to know what is called first in react so that I can make a call to load `localStorage` there .. If it is not bad idea

Answer (score 1):

You're using redux, so you should read the data as the result of an action.

The simplest way to make this work would be:

1. Under `ReduxRouter` there should be a connected component. See [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)
2. In that connected component, add `componentDidMount` to call an action `getStuffFromLocalstorage`. See [React lifecycle events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)
3. In your reducer, get what you want from localStorage and populate the state

It might be an antipattern to do it in your reducer, but it will at least make the redux-flow go around.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to fetch the local storage data from the `componentDidMount` method inside the app.js file.

Please find the official reference here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount

if you wanna update the localStorage data before the component gets unmounted you can use the method `componentWillUnmount`:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount

Comment: The Question said `at first`, so `componentDidMount` is not useful. if the components life cycles must used, this is `componentWillMount`, it happend sooner than `componentDidMount`.